# bootstrap metismenu populated by datasource in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, html-lists

I want to create a "Tree" structured menu that is generated by a datasource.
I know how to do that with an asp.net tree view or a gridview.

However recently I have grown to love bootstrap and I just love the bootstrap [mantis menu](http://demo.onokumus.com/metisMenu/).
However metismenu only seem to work on lists 'li'. Then this became a problem for me as the list I want to generate is not static is dynamic. So I can't really bind the value one by one I need to have some other way of doing this.

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to achieve this in asp.net webforms?

PS: would a repeater work for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a repeater or a listview or pretty much anything that gives you control of the output html...

You have not presented a massive amount of information to go on but I suspect that you have at least some data that contains a text value and a URL.

```
private void BindMenuData()
{
    var menuData = DataLayer.GetMenuStructure();

    rptMenu.DataSource = menuData;
    rptMenu.DataBind();
}
```

Then in your HTML/ASPX you will have something like

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptMenu" runat="Server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href='<# Eval("URL")>'><# Eval("LinkText")></a>
        </li>

    </ItemTempate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

If you then needed sub menus you would need to nest another repeater inside the item template and bind to it in the repeater itemDataBinding/Databound (Cant remember which) event.

The sub menus leads to an extra layer of complexity which could quite easily descend into a mess of spaghetti code so take some time to think it through!

Of course the fall back could always be a method which uses a string builder to generate the HTML for the menu and spit it out to  literal.... Not the best option in my opinion though!

Comment: yes what you described is exactly what I had in mind using repeater to display all my data structure. The only worries I am getting is that would that be displayed as 1 menu or multiple when using repeater

Comment: Not sure what you mean?
The above should only render one UL.. if thats what you mean?